# Complex Differentiation using definition

Tags: complex-analysis

The function  $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$, $f(x+iy)=y+ix$, is not $\mathbb{C}$-differentiable in any point, because the Cauchy-Riemann equations do not hold. It's $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=1\neq-1=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$. Is this correct?

I wonder, how one can show this using the very definition of complex differentiation $f'(z_0)=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{f(z_0+z)-f(z_0)}{z}=\ldots=\lim_{z\to 0}=\frac{y+ix}{x+iy}$. Why does this limit not exist?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the definition for $f$?

Comment: Sorry, added it! It swaps real and imaginary part.

Comment: No worries! Thanks :)

Comment: The limit along the path $z(t)=t$ is $i$, the limit along the path $z(t)=it$ is $-i$.

Answer (score 2):

If the limit were to exist, it would have to exist and be the same no matter what direction you approached from. Let us consider $z_0 = x_0+iy_0$ and see what happens when we approach along the line $y = y_0$:

$$f'(z_0) = \lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{ix}{x} = i.$$

If instead we approach along the line $x=x_0$, we have

$$f'(z_0) = \lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{y}{iy} = -i.$$

These limits are not the same (as they imply $i=0$ which is absurd).

Personally, this is the way I like to think about complex differentiation and it very naturally leads to the Cauchy-Riemann equations upon equating real and imaginary parts in the proper way.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot! Is this a common way to check that complex limits do (not) exist? I find it hard to imagine what $z\to 0$ means for general $z$.  Btw: Do you mean $f'(z_0)$ instead of $f'(0)$?

Comment: I did not, though I did make a typo and need to add more detail since you said "at any point"! You implicitly considered $z_0=0$ in your post (though I suspect that was an accident) so I reflected that appropriately. That aside, yes this is a very common way to check that complex limits do (not) exist and it is (as noted above) the same as the Cauchy-Riemann equations, more or less.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks a lot for your fast answer and the insight into the interaction between the definition and Cauchy-Riemann equations!